# Rx.NET How do I buffer stream data as a moving (sliding) window without delay?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, sliding-window, rx.net

I'm working on connecting to trading data with Rx.NET library and what I want to do is continuously buffer last 100 seconds of data and analyze it every 2 seconds.
I'm using the following Buffer method overload:

```
        tradeStream
            .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            .Subscribe(data =>
            {
                //...
            });
```

The problem now is it works as 100 seconds buffer + it waits for 2 seconds.
Is there a way to take a sort of "snapshot" of last 100 seconds immediately with certain interval?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I must confess I was wrong in my conclusions thinking it's a buffer() extension issue.

The reason why a delay happened after buffer emission was a long running task inside observer. I have found a solution that does what I expect. I just need to collect some data and call a method to process it in async thread.
And even if processing takes longer than buffering interval, the sequence is still consistent.

```
var tlist = Observable.Range(1, 100)
.Zip(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)), (i, t) => i);

var list = tlist.Publish();


list.Subscribe(b => {
Console.WriteLine(b);
});

list
.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
.SelectMany(async b =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("_", b));
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
})
.Subscribe();

list.Connect();
```

[image: code output]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need the built-in operator, `Window`, for this. There's one overload that takes two `TimeSpan`.

```
IObservable<IObservable<Trade>> query =
    tradeStream
        .Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100.0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0));
```

So that begins a new observable that lasts 100 seconds, every 2 seconds.

Comment: Nice! You should probably add a `.SelectMany(w => w.ToList())` after the `Window`, to produce the intended resulting sequence. A disadvantage of this approach might be increased memory consumption, because each buffered item is stored in multiple lists at the same time.

Comment: There certainly needs to be some sort of `.SelectMany` with a `Func<IObservable<Trade>, IObservable<?>>` to process the separate streams.